# Django Q chained queries

Tags: django, chain, django-q

I need a little help with a Django Q query im trying to string together, it looks right, but its not quite working. The query is

```
( Q(src__lte=4) & Q(src__startswith='2') ) | 
( Q(src__gt=4) & ~Q(src__istartswith='713') & ~Q(src__istartswith='281') ) )
```

what im trying to accomplish would be "select where src is less than 4 AND startsiwth 2 OR src is greater than 4 and DOES NOT start with 713 OR 281"

the result is showing src's that start with 713 and 281, what am i doing wrong here? thanks.

Comment: You have an extra bracket at the end. What are srcs? This seems very complicated. It seems you want rows with src=2, src>4, excluding src=713 or 281?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you are mixing type. is src an int or a string? be consistant.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put a bracket,

```
-->> ( <<-- (Q(src__lte=4) & Q(src__startswith='2')) | (Q(src__gt=4) & ~Q(src__istartswith='713') & ~Q(src__istartswith='281')))
```

either you have to remove the last one.

Or you didn't paste the entire line..

You may want to try this:

```
(Q(src__gt=4) & !(Q(src__startswith=u'713') | Q(src__startswith=u'281'))
```

What type of data is your 'src'? Integer or String?

Comment: There is actually a .filter( above that on the line above it. I have another query that goes like :   .filter(
                (Q(src__lte=4) & Q(src__startswith='1')) | (Q(src__gt=4) & Q(src__startswith='713') & Q(src__startswith='281')))   and it is not showing the 713 281 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'and' instead of '&'?

Comment: weird changing the first & to 'and' changes the results i get, but changing the second one does not what is the difference of using & or and ?